# Infinite products of real numbers

Tags: general-topology

Let $R$ denote the topological space of real numbers with the euclidian topology and $N$ the space of natural numbers with the discrete topology. Consider the following infinite countable product $A=R\times R\ \times ...\times\ R\ \times ...$ where the product is endowed with the product topology. Is $A$ homeomorphic to $N\times A$ (also this with the product topology)?

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is connected but $N \times A$ is not. [$N \times A$ is the disjoint union of $E\times A$ and $F\times A$ where $E$ is the set of even integers and $F$ is the set of odd integers].